# Почему в слове заповедать, заповедный, заповедник приставки ЗА и ПО входят в состав корня?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

На учебных ресурсах предлагается такой разбор: ***заповед/а/ть, заповед/н/ый, заповед/н/ик.***  В этих словах корень ***ЗАПОВЕД***-.

Я согласна с таким разбором, но хотелось бы **объяснить его**.  Почему мы не выделяем корень ***ВЕД-***, значение которого нам понятно?

При решении этого вопроса важно знать **значение приставок** ***ЗА-*** и ***ПО***-. Как выбрать это значение **по словарю?** Почему на основе корня и двух приставок образуется словообразовательный формант ***ЗАПОВЕД***-, который мы считаем корнем?